# Unix: assign variable to command

Tags: bash

I am trying to assign the path of a file to a variable so I am doing something like:

```
PATH = dirname script.sh
```

However I am getting an error. Can someone assist? Thanks.

Sincerely,

Eric Anderson

Comment: May I warn you against overwriting `PATH` variable?

Comment: You'd probably be better served creating an alias or a function.

Answer (score 4):

There can be no spaces between the variable name and the equals sign.  Also, I think you meant to run the dirname command, so what you would want is something more like this:

```
PATH=$(dirname script.sh)
```